# Perform Event Trigger on DataGrid for DragEnter causing XAML exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am working on a c# wpf project and I have run in to a problem relating to firing an trigger within the XAML.

What I am trying to achieve is when the drags a file into the grid, it should animate the background colour change but for some reason it keeps on throwing an exception as soon as I run the program. I am getting the following error:

> 'Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an
>   exception.' Line number '9' and line position '14'.

Below is the XAML code

```
<UserControl x:Class="ReportReader.UserControls.ReportDragDropControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
    <Grid AllowDrop="True" DragDrop.DragOver="Grid_DragOver"
          DragDrop.DragEnter="Grid_DragEnter" DragDrop.Drop="Grid_Drop" DragDrop.DragLeave="Grid_DragLeave">
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.DragEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation To="#cecece" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.BackgroundColor).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" FillBehavior="Stop" Duration="0.0.1" />    
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
        <TextBlock Margin="12,12,20,12" Name="txtDragDropStatus" Text="Drag file here or use file menu to load your report" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Width="835" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: try changing this `To="#cecece"` to `To="#00cecece"`?

Comment: @KingKing still getting the same error

Comment: Normally I would just write this `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"` Note that the `Grid` doesn't have `BackgroundColor`.

Comment: (Grid.BackgroundColor) == (Grid.Background)

Comment: @eranotzap thanks, I've just tried changing it from BackgroundColor to Background but I am still getting the error on the EventTrigger tag. I don't think it likes the RoutedEvent

Comment: Grid.DragEnter == DragEnter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your XAML file -

1. `BackgroundColor` is not a Dependency Property, instead use `Background`.
2. `0.0.1` is not a valid value for TimeSpan. It should be `0:0:1`.

This will work fine -

```
<ColorAnimation To="#cecece"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background)
                                            .(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                FillBehavior="Stop" Duration="0:0:1" />
```

Also, to allow animation on background property, you should set it to some default value.

```
<Grid Background="White"/>
```

I tried with this sample and its working fine on drag enter -

```
<Grid AllowDrop="True" Background="White" DragDrop.DragEnter="Grid_DragEnter">
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.DragEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                   <ColorAnimation To="#cecece"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).
                                                     (SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                   FillBehavior="Stop" Duration="0:0:1" />
                 </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
         /EventTrigger>
     </Grid.Triggers>
     <TextBlock Margin="12,12,20,12" Name="txtDragDropStatus"
                Text="Drag file here or use file menu to load your report"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, this has got rid of the exception that I was getting, however, the animation doesn't seem to be working. I've changed the duration to ``5:0:0`` in case it was happening to fast, but it is still not changing the background colour

Comment: You should set some default value for background DP so that it can be animated from that default value.

Comment: Set some default value on grid for background. Set background on grid like this -`Background="White"`.

Comment: unfortunately still no joy, the event trigger doesn't seem to be firing the animation for some reason

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm not sure what I had different, it looked the same but I copied in your sample and now its working fine. Thanks again